# Событие QGraphicsPixmapItem::hoverMoveEvent почему то активирует событие QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent (Qt C++)

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

Создал класс от QGraphicsPixmapItem и QObject

```
//----------BackGround.h----------//
class BackGround : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BackGround(const QPixmap &pixmap, QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);
    ~BackGround();    

private:
    void hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);

};
//----------BackGround.h----------//
```

и в нем перегрузил функцию hoverMoveEvent

```
//----------BackGround----------//
BackGround::BackGround(const QPixmap &pixmap, QGraphicsItem *parent) : QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
{
    BackGround::setAcceptHoverEvents(true);

}

BackGround::~BackGround()
{

}

void BackGround::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Here";
}
//----------BackGround----------//
```

Таксе создал класс на основе QGraphicsScene в котором перегрузил событие mouseMoveEvent
(для рисовки линий)

```
void paintScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    addLine(previousPoint.x(),
            previousPoint.y(),
            event->scenePos().x(),
            event->scenePos().y(),
            QPen(Qt::black,2,Qt::SolidLine,Qt::RoundCap));

    previousPoint = event->scenePos();
}
```

Теперь создаю сцену и добавляю объект BackGround

```
//paintScene класс от QGraphicsScene
scene = new paintScene();

QPixmap background_pixmap;
background_pixmap.load(":/background/background_graphicView/BackGround.png");
background_pixmap.scaled(ui->graphicsView->size().width(),ui->graphicsView->size().height(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
BackGround *background = new BackGround(background_pixmap);

scene->addItem(background);
```

И проблема в том, что при наведении курсора на область объекта background должно было срабатывать тело
события BackGround::hoverMoveEvent но у меня почему то активируется paintScene::mouseMoveEvent a тело BackGround::hoverMoveEvent никак не срабатывает. Пожалуйста подскажите почему так, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent() вызываетcя всегда, когда курсор движется в области сцены. QGraphicsPixmapItem::hoverMoveEvent(), вызывает уже сцена, передав событие объектам сцены (В данном случае объект QGraphicsPixmapItem это объект сцены). Если вы переопределили метод QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(), то вам нужно явно вызвать метод родительского класса, который вы переопределили, иначе объекты сцены не узнают о событии.

```
void paintScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    /* 
    Ваш код  
    */
    
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event); // !!!

}
```